# Local Npm module "GRUNT-PLUGIN-MODULE" not found. Is it installed? What's causing this?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-plugins

How to load your new grunt-plugin module to your project.

example of dir structure:

```
|-- abc-project
|       |-- ...
|       |-- app.js
|       |-- Gruntfile.js --> `grunt.loadNpmTasks('my-grunt-plugin');`
|       \-- package.json
|
\-- my-grunt-plugin
      |-- grunt-tasks
      |       |-- task-a.js --> `grunt.registerTask('task-a', 'running task a', function() { ... });`
      |       \-- task-b.js
      \-- ...
```

- run `npm link` command inside `my-grunt-plugin` dir.
- link your local grunt plugin module by running `npm link my-grunt-plugin` command inside `abc-project` dir.
- run `grunt task-a` command, it will log `Local Npm module "my-grunt-plugin" not found. Is it installed?`

Comment: I get this same error when I run `grunt` on my project (any task).  It seems to have just started showing up.  I see `Local Npm module "grunt-plugin" not found. Is it installed?`   There was a `grunt-plugin` folder in my `node_modules`.  I tried `npm link` from within that folder, and I also tried deleting the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this case is the task dir name in the `my-grunt-plugin`.
You need to make sure that the name of task dir is always `tasks` NOT `grunt-tasks`.

Comment: This worked for me, even though it seemed I had a different issue (see my comment on the question).

Simply did a `mkdir node_modules/grunt-plugin/tasks` and I no longer see the warning!  Strange, but glad it's fixed.